# jQuery Hover Mouseout Firing Too Early On List Dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have attached a snippet below of my problem. When I mouse over too many of my menu items, the dropdown it is supposed to trigger will `.slideUp()` too early. The logic that it should be operating under is simple:

1. If mouseover - keep it's associated dropdown.
2. If mouseout - lose its associated dropdown.
3. If mouse over the dropdown, keep the dropdown showing.

Right now it seems (2) doesn't always work, because if you mouseover one element than another, that second element will instantly lose its dropdown even if the mouse remains over it.

Please assist, it seems to only work if you wait a bit and hit one menu item at a time deliberately to trigger the dropdown, but obviously this is not how users will behave.

**EDIT:** I need a JavaScript solution given the particulars of the CSS of my page, which make a nested CSS solution not desirable.

```js
jQuery(".header2 li a").mouseover(function(event){

jQuery(".dropdown").css('display','none');

});
jQuery(".header2 li a").hover(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 $id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 
    jQuery("."+$id +".boxs").stop().slideDown(); //id of href is a class on .boxs/.dropdown for targetting
},function (event) {
$id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (  jQuery("."+$id+".boxs").hasClass('active')) {
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
              jQuery("."+$id +".boxs").slideUp();
     console.log($id);
        }
    }, 500);
});
 jQuery(".dropdown").mouseenter(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    jQuery(this).show();
});
 jQuery(".dropdown").mouseleave(function () {
    jQuery(this).slideUp();
    jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.header2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header2 li a{
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxs header2">
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="active active1">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/category/news" class="" id="news">News</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/category/featured" class="" id="f">Featured</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/category/gear" class="" id="another">Another Dropdown</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/category/the-journal" class="" id="one_more">One More! </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--DROPDOWNS BELOW-->

<div class="news boxs dropdown" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="boxs">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><h3>News From</h3></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Capitol Hill</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>The White House</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>

<div class="f boxs dropdown" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="boxs">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><h3>News From</h3></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Toronto</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Quebec</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>

<div class="another boxs dropdown" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="boxs">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><h3>Zookeepers</h3></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Lions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Tigers</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>

<div class="one_more boxs dropdown" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="boxs">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><h3>Milk</h3></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>1%</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>2%</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$id = jQuery(this).attr('id');`
`jQuery("."+$id +".boxs").stop().slideDown();`                                                                   these two lines look problematic to me, as not everyone of your links under `header2 li` have `id` properties attached, also the second line above puts a `.` in front of an `id` value, it should be a `#`

Comment: Move the dropdown divs into their associated li. So when you hover the li and the dropdown you dont't "mouseout" the li, which makes it easy for you to handle to mouse events.

Comment: @RyanWilson it's because the `id` of the anchor tag of the first list is a class name on the dropdown `div`. So the anchor tag has an `id='f'` and the `dropdown` has a class `f`. It's just a way to select the dropdown based off the id of the hovered over anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

It would make much more sense to use a nested, multilevel `ul` hierarchy for these options as it's the separate `div` elements (and the subsequent gaps between them) which are causing the problem.

If you use nested `ul` elements you can make this work in CSS alone, like this:

```css
.header2 > li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.header2 > li > ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.header2 > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="boxs header2">
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/category/news">News</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>News From</h3>
      </li>
      <li>Capitol Hill</li>
      <li>The White House</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/category/featured">Featured</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>News From</h3>
      </li>
      <li>Toronto</li>
      <li>Quebec</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/category/gear">Another Dropdown</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Zookeepers</h3>
      </li>
      <li>Lions</li>
      <li>Tigers</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/category/the-journal">One More! </a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Milk</h3>
      </li>
      <li>1%</li>
      <li>2%</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using CSS alone makes the logic more extensible (you just add more `li` and `ul` elements for more menu items without affecting the JS) and also perform better.

Comment: Hi sorry, this was a great answer but unfortunately my CSS needs to get it to look right on the page given my design mean I can't use nested elements like this, if you could edit your answer to include a solution given my JavaScript/HTML that would be great, sorry to bother you. My question is really on why my JavaScript doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I'd suggest changing your CSS in that case.